# Taking lock to serialize

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, io, locking

I am new to Java.
I am practicing by writing small programs.

In one of the programs I have an object that holds some configuration.
This configuration can be changed at runtime. 
I am saving the configuration to file by serializing the object.

It seems to me that I must take a lock on the object that I am serializing before Serialization, to make sure it wouldn't change during the Serialization.

```
synchronized (myObject)
{
    output.writeObject(myObject);
}
```

However I've read that one should try to avoid IO operation (such as writing to file) in synchronized block or under any other form of lock. It does make sense, since IO operation might take relatively long time, keeping other threads waiting/blocked.

I wonder, whether there is a way to avoid Serialization under lock...
Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: You realize that just that synchronized block alone won't prevent concurrent modifications, right?

Comment: @shmosel I know that I need to make sure that all modifications of myObject occur in a synchronized block/method to make sure that this synchronized block will protect me during Serialization. But it is nice of you to make sure I am aware of tha, thanks.

Comment: I don't agree with what you've read. It's done all the time in socket programming.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your comment. Nice to hear a different opinion, especially being new to the language.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions to this problem are:

1. Only serialize immutable objects
2. Create a copy of the object and serialize the copy

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case the object is not immutable. I've considered making a copy of the object. In my case the object is small and the copy is relatively "cheap" option. But in case of bigger objects (such is List) this solution seems to me quite costly.

Answer (score 0):

But what happens in the interval between setting the object and starting to flush it? You could still end up having written another object.

A possible solution could be to lock the object only for writing after having modified it and unlock first when it has been flushed. Locking and unlocking could be done through acquiring and releasing a [binary semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

So, `acquire()` a permit before writing to the object variable and `release` one after having serialized. This will block only active *Modifier-threads* and effectively allow further concurrent execution. This will avoid the I/O polling in your example.

One problem is that there could be a second context switch from the *Writer-thread* - after having written it and just before releasing the lock. But, if you are OK with letting the *Modifier-thread*(s) wait a bit more, this is then a no worry.

Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all, thank for introducing me to Semaphore class, didn't get to see it yet, was interesting to read about it.

Comment: I also like the names you've given to the threads, Modifiers and Writer, makes the discussion easier. It seems that even with using Semaphore one issue still remains - Modifiers block while Writer performs a time-consuming IO operation. I think the benefit of using Semaphore is that instead of affecting all synchronized blocks/method, we are affecting only those waiting for specific semaphore. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly - only those that have to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the serialization process inside lock as your use case required that during write no one should able to modify .

1.Basic solution will be reduce the execution time by  Use the transient keyword to reduce the amount of data serialized. Additionally, customized readObject() and writeObject() methods may be beneficial in some cases.

2.If possible you can modify your logic so that you can split your lock So that multiple thread can read /but not able to modify.

3.You can use pattern like use  in collection where iteration may take long time so they clone the original object before iteration.